# How to convert a C++ vector to a numpy vector in Cython whilst minimising Python interpreter interaction?

Tags: python, numpy, cython

Specifically:

- How to provide `numpy.ndarray` as a function output data type and
- How to use `cimport numpy` instead of `import numpy` to create an array without Python overhead?

The code below works if `numpy.ndarray` is removed from the line `cdef numpy.ndarray array(int start, int end):`. According to the annotation it still has a lot of Python overhead (excluding the `range(start, end)` initialisation of the C++ vector).

```
%%cython -a
# distutils: language = c++

import numpy
from libcpp.vector cimport vector


cdef numpy.ndarray array(int start, int end):
    cdef vector[int] vect = range(start, end)
    return numpy.array(vect)

print(array(1,15))
```

Comment: [This isn't quite a duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45133276/passing-c-vector-to-numpy-through-cython-without-copying-and-taking-care-of-me) but it is pretty relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NumPy arrays are Python object. If you wish to work with them at the compiled level you should use [memoryviews](http://docs.cython.org/en/latest/src/userguide/memoryviews.html) that are supported by Cython. You can then require a `np.asarray(cython_memoryview_variable)` to go to Python.

As your base object is a C++ vector, there is no automatic conversion of its content to a NumPy arrray, so you have to work that out explicitly (at the cost of a copy).